# Is different vote scores a bug or intentional?

Tags: bug, status-completed, votes

Just spotted this.  Is it a bug?

Two downvotes in question[image: 2 down votes in question]

but only one downvote in the list
[image: 1 down vote in list]

Comment: The question lists (such as the home page) use cached data that can take a few minutes to update.

Answer (score 4):

It's appearing with two downvotes in the Top Questions list for me (as of now).

The question was flagged as "very low quality", so once I accepted that, the Community User (the system) automatically downvoted it per the user's flag.

Maybe you're seeing something different because you or someone else downvoted it after clicking on the link to the Top Questions page. Try refreshing the page, or logging out and back in again. If not, it might be displayed that way because the same person both flagged and downvoted it...

Comment: Nope...once I noticed it I specifically tried to hard reload both pages to be certain.  But I see @Stephen Ostermiller's comment on the question that the question list uses cached data.  That's what is going on I suspect.

Comment: I've found that logging out and then back in again (as indicated above) usually clears up issues like that, including votes on closing/reopening and review statuses. I've changed the status to completed since it's not really a bug, but an artifact.

Comment: Interesting that accepted answers update immediately though.